# How should I go about parsing and using website data? I am using node js

Tags: html, node.js, parsing, bufferedreader

I am using node js to create a bot that gets stats from r6.tracker.network, but when I load it in the data won't show up unlike when I have 'www.google.com' as the host. I don't really know where to go from here. I'm trying to use several different debugging methods, but I haven't found anything yet. There is no output.

```
function getWebpage(parameter){
const pathuser = '/profile/pc/' + parameter;
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'r6.tracker.network',
    path: '/'
}
var request = http.request(options, function (res) {
    
    var data = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
request.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
});
request.end();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are redirecting you to the `https` version of their site.

The key here is to add this logging:

```
console.log(res.statusCode);
console.log(res.headers.location);
```

When you do that, you will see this:

```
301
https://r6.tracker.network/
```

In other words, they want you to use the https version of their site and they are redirecting you to do that.  You won't get the content of the web page from the http URL.  You have to use https.

Coding takeaways here:

1. Always look at the http status and only proceed normally if you get a 2xx response.
2. Be prepared for 3xx redirect responses.

FYI, if you use a more modern library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) or any of the other libraries listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143), they will all follow redirects for you automatically and they will gather the full response for you automatically too.  And, they use the more modern promise-based method of asynchronous programming.  I'd really suggest you pick one of those libraries for your outbound http requests.

Comment: Thank you so much! Once I get finished with the reader, I'll try to implement that.

Comment: @BaccaRulerMC - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: yeah. I'm also brand new to this language and even though it's similar to java. I have another question about the code but the it's more about chunking. Do I post a new discussion thread or edit this one since the code block is the same.

Comment: @BaccaRulerMC - You would post a new question.